# Are these improper ways of using LINQ?

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Just wondering if these are improper ways of using LINQ. They work, just don't know if they're breaking anything.

// Example 1: Getting a string from an XML element (here, I'm skipping the LINQ query)

```
measurements.a = (string)bm.Descendants("a").SingleOrDefault();
```

// Example 2: Using Descendants to "drill in" till I get to the element I want. 
// the reason why i have 2 Descendants here is because "b" needs to be a child of "a"

```
measurements.title = (from e in bm.Descendants("a").Descendants("b")
                                    select e.Value).SingleOrDefault();
```

Thanks for your time. :)
James

Comment: Watch out with SingleOrDefault.  It has three possible outcomes:  If one result - return that result.  If no results, return the default result.  If many results - throw exception.   If you don't like that last possibility, I recommend using FirstOrDefault instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my eyes these are perfectly correct. The only thing to note is that you might want to get the value of an XElement, rather than the element itself:

```
var a = (string)bm.Descendants("a").SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

If you cast a single descendant as a string, but it contains complex content (e.g. child elements) rather than a string, you might fall into problems.